# SignTool error when signing AppX file: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147024693/0x800700cb)

Tags: windows-store-apps, signtool, appx

I am creating an Appx package using `makeappx.exe` and then try to sign it using `SignTool.exe`.

The error I get from SignTool is:

> "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147024693/0x800700cb)

The certificate I am using is created by me following instructions from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In `EventViewer` there is no record about this failed operation!

I do not understand what this error means and how to fix it!!
Has anyone encountered this before, and found a solution?

I can't use Visual Studio so I need to stick with `makeappx.exe`.

Comment: It is a Windows error, ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND.  The signtool /nph option is documented to use an environment variable.  Just blind guessing as long as you don't document your question properly.  Anyhoo, something "environmental".

Comment: The full command line passed to `SignTool.exe` is:
`SignToolexe sign /a /f  cert.pfx /fd SHA256 /v /debug myPackage.appx`

MSDN says about `/nph` option:
_If supported, suppresses page hashes for executable files. The default behavior is determined by the SIGNTOOL_PAGE_HASHES environment variable and by the Wintrust.dll version. This option is ignored for non-PE files._

I dont have any PE files in package so it does not apply.

Answer (score 4):

The appxmanifest xml file needs to have a publisher that corresponds to the certificate that is signing the appx package.
The publisher is specified in an attribute for the "<Identity />" tag.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835835(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The app manifest publisher name must exactly match the subject name of the signing.
>   Note  These names are specified in quotes and are both case and whitespace sensitive.
>   You can update the Publisher attribute string that is defined for the Identity element in the AppxManifest.xml file to match the subject name of the intended signing certificate. Or, select a different signing certificate with a subject name that matches the app manifest publisher name. The manifest publisher name and the certificate subject name are both listed in the event message.
>
> Example error:
>
> error 0x8007000B: The app manifest publisher name (CN=Contoso) must match the subject name of the signing certificate (CN=Contoso, C=US).

Comment: I am receiving error **0x800700cb**, not **0x8007000B** !

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that hidden C!  :(  No idea on that one then.

Comment: did you try looking up more details in the event log? (as suggested in the linked MSDN article)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I just had a similar problem with the signer tool, but different error code. Though, I think the comment was relevant:

> Turns out you can get this error too if you use the wrong version of
> the SignTool, but it give no clue to this fact.
>
> So the top tip is …
>
> Make sure you use the SignTool.exe from the same folder as the
> MakeAppx.exe tool. In  my case in “C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64\”

Cross-linking should help this page get a higher page ranking on the search engines.

https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/rfennell/2019/04/30/a-fix-for-error-signersign-failed-2146958839-0x80080209-with-signtool-exe/

Comment: Amazing. This was exactly my problem! Thanks very much